# Automatically redirect URLs generated by Vercel's production deployments to custom domains

Tags: firebase, next.js, sentry, vercel, firebase-app-check

If you are deploying to Vercel for production and you have set up a custom domain, you can access the same page from the following three URLs.

```
1. https://[vercelProjectName]-[vercelUserName].vercel.app
2. https://[vercelProjectName]-[deployId]-[vercelUserName].vercel.app
3. https://[myDomain].com
```

Furthermore, all of them exist independently, without being redirected to a custom domain.

However, it seems that URLs in 1. are not registered with search engines, so you can leave them alone.
[Are Vercel Preview Deployments indexed by search engines? – Vercel Docs](https://vercel.com/support/articles/are-vercel-preview-deployment-indexed-by-search-engines)

Still, the URLs for 2. and 3. are duplicated.
Is there any way to redirect the user to URL 3. when accessing URL 2. ?

---

## Detail

I'm deploying an application consisting of `Next.js`, `Firebase` and `Sentry` to `Vercel`.
In addition, I use [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) to make sure that `Firebase storage` cannot be manipulated by anyone other than authorized domains.

And yesterday, when I installed Sentry, I had the following error in URL2.

```
@firebase/app-check: FirebaseError: AppCheck: Fetch server returned an HTTP error status. HTTP status: 403. (appCheck/fetch-status-error).
```

The URL in 2. is not allowed by `App Check`, which is probably causing the above error.
Also, the above error occurs once per 15 to 30 minutes.
The error is caused by the following execution environment.
[image]
I don't know if it's Google's crawler or what, but there's something running around.
I want to redirect this guy running around who came to URL 2. to URL 3.

---

The URLs in 1. 2. 3. have `canonical` set in the head as shown below.

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://[myDomain].com">
```

However, the `noindex` is not included in the head tags of pages 1. and 2.